# Is there way to declare an abstract component in Angular so that it can be used in a template?

Tags: angular, templates, components, abstract, angular-components

I would like to create an abstract component in my Angular application that has a template that can be reused by my components that extend the abstract one. Below is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-abstract',
  templateUrl: '<ng-content></ng-content> {{ title }} Component',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export abstract class AbstractComponent implements OnInit {

  title: string;  

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.methodDefinedByExtenders();
  }

  protected abstract methodDefinedByExtenders();
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-extender-one',
  templateUrl: '<app-abstract>This is the <app-abstract/>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ExtenderOneComponent extends AbstractComponent {
  protected methodDefinedByExtenders(): void { this.title = 'Cool Extender One'; };
}
```

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AbstractComponent --> this gives issue,
    ExtenderOneComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The idea here is that ExtenderOne's template would show 'This is the Cool Extender One Component' by making use of its parent's title field and ngOnInit hook. The problem here is that I get the following error:

```
Type 'typeof AbstractComponent' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'.
    Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
```

I'd really like to be able to take advantage of using the template of the AbstractComponent so that I can wrap all my components that Extend AbstractComponent in a common template. I know I can remove AbstractComponent from my declarations and continue to use it in the .ts file but reusing the template would save us a lot of writing. Thanks!

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: unfortunately i didnt. Still having to share common code in the .ts file while creating a new template with duplicate code for each component extending the base class. We *could* create a second component that extends the base component and supplies the template and then have a ton of child components that also extend the base component but reference the template component in their own template

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare in your module the abstract component, but only the components that extend from it and that you actually use/instantiate.

In your case, you would only need to declare `ExtenderOneComponent` and any other component extending from `AbstractComponent`, but not `AbstractComponent` itself.

EDIT: Components' HTML templates are never extended from one component to another, only class members.

Comment: in order to use the template from AbstractComponent like <app-abstract></app-abstract> it has to be declared it seems

Comment: So what do you say, Jago? If an abstract component has its own markup - you cannot skip adding it to DECLARATION. And here we go: abstract class cannot be added there. And what is the way out? To resolve this issue, I had to make an abstract class not abstract. But from design perspective, it was not a good solution, because I have some properties which better be abstract and implemented by the inherited class.